# matlab2tikz/pgfplots adding colorbar afterwards

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab2tikz

I am currently using both `matlab2tikz` and `pgfplots` with external graphics since I am not completely convinced by either yet.

Is it possible to add a colorbar with any of the two afterwards (meaning the original MATLAB figure is not open anymore, and therefore I can not check for the minimum and maximum values anymore)?

If I run `matlab2tikz` on a MATLAB figure with the colorbar open, `matlab2tikz` will place the correct colorbar automatically, if  added afterwards it will always only give a scale from 0-1 as `point meta min` and `point meta max` are of course not specified. Is it possible to modify 
`matlab2tikz` such that `point meta min` and `point meta max` are always saved to the .tikz file?

If i use `pgfplots` with external graphics, I will always have to assign `point meta min` and `point meta max` manually. Is there any way around this when using pgfplots?

P.S. I am aware that it is possible to export the entire dataset from MATLAB and import it to `pgfplots`. However I would like to avoid this as the datasets are rather big (including quite some meshes) and the total amount of pictures in the final report will be >100.

Comment: Since you explicitly ask for a modification of `matlab2tikz`, you may want to post requests on http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz .

Comment: I am almost always downsampling the data and importing the dataset (via LuaTeX it can handle around 10K points). It's a personal thing but I can't stand matlab handling the export or the graphics.